# How are the attribute prefixes "x-" and "data-" used in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular and trying to understand what the "x-" and "data-" prefixes mean. In the directives documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) it says that these prefixes will make the directive "HTML validator compliant". What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The HTML5 spec allows for arbitrary attributes as long as they're prefixed with data- like so:

```
<div data-myattribute=""></div>
```

Whereas this would be invalid HTML5:

```
<div myattrbute=""></div>
```

[For more information on data- attributes, have a look here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

As for "x-" attributes, I think you mean "x:" attributes and elements, which are specific to XHTML validation...

To expand on this, if you were to (for some reason) be using XHTML, you can define custom attributes with namespacing like so (and I'm just summarizing the gist here):

```
<html xmlns:x="http://sample.com/mynamespace">
<body>
   <div x:whatever=""></div>
   <x:mytag></x:mytag>
</body>
</html>
```

where the URL in xmlns is really just to prevent conflicts between like elements. Also, a DTD for the custom elements and attributes could be provided for validation purposes as a part of your DOCTYPE declaration.

*behavior in browsers is going to vary with this xmlns approach.

In summary, though: **With most browsers released in the last three years, or IE8+ you're not going to have to worry about any of these things.** Only in very specific situations will you really care.

Comment: The document the OP links does say that `data-myattribute` and `x-myattribute` are HTML validator compliant.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what validator the document's author uses... but x-attribute is currently [not in the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html).

Comment: Fair enough, I did try to find more information on the `x-` but as you can imagine the term is impossible to Google. It chiefly turns up in experimental browser features like `x-moz-errormessage` and `x-webkit-speech`.

Comment: Haha... yeah, I did the same, because I was like "I don't remember ever seeing this in the spec... what is this about?" Then I looked at the spec and didn't see it, so I started Googling. It sure is strange that the link above speaks of x-attributes like it's a really common thing.

Comment: Does this mean that Angular treats an attribute called `data-mynamespace` as if it were declared simply as `mynamespace`?

Comment: The answer states that x is related to XHTML. Is this correct? From what I read in HTML5 spec, and the other answer by KevinButler, x is not XHTML, but browser specific attributes. I don't want to edit this answer though incase I am wrong/misunderstanding. Can someone else who is more knowledgeable about this add some more info? It seems important to update this, as I keep finding this on google when reading about x/data

Comment: @Redfox05 `whatever:tagname` is notation for `xmlns` or xml namespacing  which is a feature of XHTML. `x-` is indeed reserved for the user agent's usage but in terms of the user agent's vendor such as `x-vendor-***`. Apologies that my answer was vague.

It should also be noted that these specs are likely to change out from underneath this answer as the answer ages.

Comment: @BenLesh, ahhh, I understand what you were saying now, I didnt realise the reference to ":" instead of "-". Your answer says `As for "x-" attributes, I think you mean "x:" attributes and elements, which are specific to XHTML validation` But in terms of AngularJS, the OP meant x-, not the x: that you are referring to, as the issue is that Angular can be used with data-ng-*, or x-ng-*, and its hard to understand which is the right one to use. As I understand it, both do the same, so its a matter of html spec and compatibility?

Comment: @BenLesh It looks like you use angular in a non-trivial environment. Do you personally use data-ng-blah or ng-blah? What made you choose one over the other (or, if it was directed by powers that be, why did they choose one over the other?)

Answer (score 19):

From the HTML5 spec: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html

> Attribute names beginning with the two characters "x-" are reserved
>   for user agent use and are guaranteed to never be formally added to
>   the HTML language.

Also:

> For markup-level features that are intended for use with [the HTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#syntax),
>       extensions should be limited to new attributes of the form "`x-vendor-feature`", where
>   vendor is a short
>       string that identifies the vendor responsible for the extension, and feature is the
>       name of the feature. New element names should not be created. Using attributes for such
>       extensions exclusively allows extensions from multiple vendors to co-exist on the same element,
>       which would not be possible with elements. Using the "`x-vendor-feature`" form allows
>   extensions to be made
>       without risk of conflicting with future additions to the specification.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say the "x-" prefix is the CORRECT way to use angular if you want validating markup.  It's really data.

From W3C draft:
"For markup-level features... extensions should be limited to new attributes of the form 'x-vendor-feature'"

Ng attributes with the x- prefix fit this description beautifully.

Comment: +1. Does the wording here seem to be referring to browser vendors rather than library/frameworks, though? Regardless, this feels more correct to me than using a data prefix as it's more specific to the framework than bits of data you may want to attach (and also follows the x-vendor prefixing of the draft).

Comment: I agree with wbyoung, to the letter of the law x- is reserved for the browser, not extensions or frameworks. However, I also think they should amend the law to include this usage, as 'x-ng-feature' appears like a semantically correct convention.

Comment: From the same link, "Pages that use such attributes are by definition non-conforming."
If validation is the motivation to use 'x-*' attributes, then it looks like the better thing would be to use 'data-*'