# ng-app is not valid attribute of element 'HTML'

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJs and while I am using ng-app and ng-view in HTML file, it is saying these are not valid attributes of element in HTML

Can any one suggest

Here is sample code:

```
<html **ng-app**= "XXXXX" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div **ng-view**></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stop stressing over HTML validity if you know what you're doing. The chances are vanishingly small that HTML will, at any point, standardise any attribute starting with `ng-`, and no browser you need to care about will not ever do anything to break invalid attributes.

Comment: Who is this "it" you're talking about?

Answer (score 36):

I assume this is just a warning, in which case you can just ignore it. If you are using a recent version of AngularJS and you are targeting HTML5, you can prepend `data-` to the attribute name (e.g. `data-ng-app`) and the warning should go away.

Comment: @RahulRavipati There are several other alternatives. You can also prefix the attributes with "x-" for this purpose: `x-ng-app="appName"`. It's discussed on the [3rd paragraph of this page](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: well when I am using data prefix for ng-app and defining ng-view as "class='ng-view' ", its not throwing any errors thanks for suggestions @Daniel Pratt && Sunil D but required page is not loading

Comment: It may not be loading because you are telling the browser that the page markup is XHTML (the xmlns attribute). Unless you have a good reason to keep it that way, I'd recommend using an HTML5 doctype instead.

Comment: Although Angular may understand the `x-` prefix, attributes prefixed as such will not be valid according to the HTML5 spec.

Comment: Hi Daniel Pratt, I have been using data prefix for ng-app its working but for ng-view its working same and if i declare it as class='ng-view' its not throwing any error but i doubt whether the functionality is changing in any way because of this !! Thank you

Comment: @DanielPratt [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17902387/98069) on a similar question seems to indicate that they are allowed by the spec. It seems a bit vague to me… thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is simple fix by adding "data-" for every ang-js directive

incase if you are using netbeans as editor,

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=224637

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you're not loading javascript for angular-route:

```
<script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your editor back from Web Form to regular HTML by right click on your doc in Solution Explorer and say "Open with".

I am using VS 2017. All my ng-.. directives are off after I opened my html doc with HTML (Web Forms) Editor.  They all showed up again when I switched the editor back to HTML Editor (Default).

[image: Click here for pic]

Answer (score 0):

You must add a prefix: "data-"

Like this:

```
data-ng-app
```