# How add custom attribute in zend framework 2 using zend from

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework2, zend-form, custom-attributes

I want to use angularJS in a zend framework project and in this project forms are generated using zend form. How can I add angular directive such as "ng-model" in the form elements but whenever i was trying to add this custom attribute in the zend-form elements (input, select etc) in view I am not getting this attribute ----

Here is my lead form

class LeadForm extends Form {

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct('lead_form');

    $this->setAttributes(array(
        'action' => '',
        'method' => 'post',
        'name' => 'lead_form',
        'id' => 'lead_form',
        'class' => 'smart-form',
        'role' => 'form',
        'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'first_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'First Name',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]',                
            'placeholder' => 'First name',                
            **'ng-model' => "first_name", // this attribute is not generating in view**
        ),            
    ));
}
```

}

Here is my controller which is calling this form and send to view for displaying

```
$createLeadForm = new \Admin\Form\LeadForm();

return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $createLeadForm,
));
```

Here is my code in view for showing element

```
<?php echo $this->formInput($this->form->get('first_name')); ?>
```

**But after prinnting this form element i am getting see no "ng-model" in the input element**

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="First name" class="form-control validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]" name="first_name" >
```

**I have set one attribute "ng-model " but this attribute is not appearing in the view**

**I want this element like (using zend form ) -**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="first_name" value="" placeholder="First name" class="form-control validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]" name="first_name" >
```

How can I do that using zend form and what need to change in this form and why i can not able to add custom attribute? please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5):

You always can use data-ng-*:

```
$this->add(array(
    // ...
    'attributes' => array(
        // ...
        'data-ng-model' => 'first_name',
    ),            
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering. I can see that I can use 'data-ng-model' attribute in the form input element but can not able to use 'ng-model' in the input element. **For working with angular I have to add 'ng-model' attribute using zend form.** Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: uhmmm angular also works with data-* :) and... it is even better... take a look at this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589853/ng-app-vs-data-ng-app-what-is-the-difference

Answer (score 0):

Zend does not support other attribute if that attribute start other than data-* so for adding attribute for ng-* I had to modify the View Helper class

under this namespace ( Zend\Form\View\Helper ) inside the main library you will find a class named "AbstractHelper" and in this class you can get a method named "prepareAttributes" and here you have to change the following lines -

```
if (!isset($this->validGlobalAttributes[$attribute])
   && !isset($this->validTagAttributes[$attribute])
   && 'data-' != substr($attribute, 0, 5)
)
```

to

```
if (!isset($this->validGlobalAttributes[$attribute])
   && !isset($this->validTagAttributes[$attribute])
   && 'data-' != substr($attribute, 0, 5)
   && 'ng-' != substr($attribute, 0, 3)
)
```

see here I add

```
&& 'ng-' != substr($attribute, 0, 3)
```

so that ng-* attributes can be added using zend form

Thanks Again

Comment: Whoa, whoa, did you just suggest editing the Zend library files directly? This is an absolute no-no - your Zend library files should be stand-alone from the rest of your project, and editing those files means if you upgrade your Zend version or give your project to someone else, it won't work. At the very least, you should be INHERITING the Zend View helper in your own helper and making the required changes in your own project. As a general rule, anything inside Vendor shouldn't to be changed unless it's your own.

Comment: How would one do what this post suggests without editing the core Zend framework? As this actually fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
class FooForm extends Form
{

    public function __construct(LookupService $lookupService)
    {

        parent::__construct('fooForm');
        $this->setAttribute('novalidate', true);
    }

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (data attribute)

ZF2:

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct('lead_form');

    $this->setAttributes(array(
        'action' => '',
        'method' => 'post',
        'name' => 'lead_form',
        'id' => 'lead_form',
        'class' => 'smart-form',
        'role' => 'form',
        'novalidate' => 'novalidate'
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'first_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'First Name',
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]]',
            'placeholder' => 'First name',
            'data-ng'     => json_encode(
                array(
                    'ng-model' => 'first_name',
                    'ng-123'   => '123',
                ), true
            )
        ),
    ));
}
```

Call this JS function after your HTML-Manipulation:

```
/**
 * ZF2 supports no custom attributs
 * this function converts data-ng attributes to ng attributes
 */
function addNgAttributes() {
    $('[data-ng]').each(function () {
        var ngdata = $(this).data('ng');
        var _this = this;
        $.each(ngdata, function (key, value) {
            $(_this).attr(key, value)
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extend Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormFile and replace it via factory:

```
    namespace YourNamespace;    

    use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormFile;

    class FormFile extends FormFile {

        /**
         * Attributes valid for the input tag type="file"
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $validTagAttributes = [
            'name' => true,
            'accept' => true,
            'autofocus' => true,
            'disabled' => true,
            'form' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'type' => true,
            'yourCustomAttribute' => true, //<--- here add Your attribute
        ];        

    }
```

and in module.php:

```
    public function getViewHelperConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormFile' => function($sm) {
                $helper = new \YourNamespace\FormFile();
                return $helper;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

then You can use yourCustomAttribute in form class as other attributes.