# Eclipse with AngularJs showing ugly warnings on HTML editor.

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

With Eclipse, AngularJs development, the following line shows an error/warning in the HTML editor.

```
<body ng-app>
```

And the following does not.

```
<body data-ng-app>
```

Is there anyway I could use the first variant and still not have the ugly warnings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined attribute name (ng-model) at Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280822/undefined-attribute-name-ng-model-at-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any Eclipse plugins in use that support AngularJS development? If not, you might want to check http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse

> provides an HTML editor which supports AngularJS expression and directive