# Angular JS ng-switch-when is not working

Tags: angularjs, html

I've something like below. I am binding countries to a dropdown.

I selected Country value `India`. But below switch default is calling.

```
 <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="selectedCountry" data-ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
 </select>
```

-

```
<div class="animate-switch-container" data-ng-switch on="{{selectedCountry.name}}">
<div class="animate-switch" data-ng-switch-when="USA">
     USA
</div>

<div class="animate-switch" data-ng-switch-when="India">
     India
</div>

<div class="animate-switch" data-ng-switch-default>
     Other Country
</div>
```

I also tried with `data-ng-switch-when="'India'"`

Any solution please?

Comment: look example https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch data-ng-switch on="selectedCountry.name"

Comment: Remove brackets within `on` attribute. Apart form that, why all the `data-`?

Comment: remove brackets {{}} in data-ng-switch on

Comment: @BroiSatse. Because of this (use data-ng-app if you would like validating your HTML to be a bit easier.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589853/ng-app-vs-data-ng-app-what-is-the-difference).

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, data-ng-switch on="selectedCountry.id-selectedCountry.name"    and data-ng-switch-when="1-India" is valid?

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi that "best practice" is quickly dying.  You're better off moving away from it.  Validators need to catch up; don't enable them :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/IE14ikbSlNAl3Kz03P3Y ...

Comment: @DavidL thanks :). Removed all data- from my project.