# How to fix "Warning: Unknown prop `ng-app` on <body> tag. Remove this prop from the element" error?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to render a webpage through React with the addition of some code the uses Angular. I packaged my page with Webpack. When I run my HTML, I get the following errors:

```
Warning: Unknown prop `ng-app` on <body> tag. Remove this prop from the element.

Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <body> cannot appear as a child of <div>.

Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?

Warning: Unknown props `change-background`, `colorcode` on <div> tag. 

Warning: Unknown prop `ng-click` on <li> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
```

My HTML is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssWEB.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JSX file is:

```
import angular from 'angular';


angular.module('App', [])
  .directive('changeBackground', ['$animate', function($animate) {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        colorcode: '@?'
      },
      link: function($scope, element, attr) {
        element.on('mouseenter', function() {
          element.children().addClass('change-color');
          element.children().css('background-color', $scope.colorcode);
        });
        element.on('mouseleave', function() {
          element.children().removeClass('change-color');
          element.children().css('background-color', '@red');
        });
      }
    };
  }]).directive('myClick', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: (scope) => {
        scope.clicked = () => {
          console.log('pppp');
          window.location.hash = "#snap1";
        }
      }
    };
  }).directive('click2', () => {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: (scope) => {
        scope.clicked2 = () => {
          console.log("aaaaaa");
        }
      }
    }
  })

//REACT//
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Element, scroller} from 'react-scroll';


const Component = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        scroller.scrollTo('myScroller', {
            duration: 1500,
            delay: 500,
            smooth: true
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
              <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="style.less" type="text/css" />
              <script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>
              <link type="text/javascript" href="jscode.js"></link>


              <header>
                My Page
              </header>

              <body ng-app="App">
                <div class="cube" change-background colorcode="#f45642" ref={(el) => { this.messagesEnd = el; }}>
                  <div class="front"><span>Resume</span></div>
                  <div class="back"></div>
                  <div class="top"></div>
                  <div class="bottom"></div>
                  <div class="left"></div>
                  <div class="right"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap2">
                  <div class="cube" change-background>
                    <div class="front" colorcode="#f45642"><span>Work</span></div>
                    <div class="back"></div>
                    <div class="top"></div>
                    <div class="bottom"></div>
                    <div class="left"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap3">
                  <div class="cube" change-background>
                    <div class="front" colorcode="#f45642"><span>Contact</span></div>
                    <div class="back"></div>
                    <div class="top"></div>
                    <div class="bottom"></div>
                    <div class="left"></div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </body>

              <Element name="link1">
                <div class="bg2" id="linkhere"></div>
              </Element>

              <div class="slide1">
              </div>

              <div class="slidechild1">
              <div class="centerbox">
              <div class="center">
                <ul>
                  <li ng-click="clicked2()" id="B1">aa</li>
                  <li id="B2">cc.i</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

What is raising these errors regarding props? Is this a problem caused by having my file to be .jsx? How can I fix them?

Update:

Using Mathew Cawley's answer I manged to fix some of the errors by using data-ng-app instead of ng-app in all of my ng directives. Now I get the following errors:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <body> cannot appear as a child of <div>.

Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?

Warning: Unknown props `change-background`, `colorcode` on <div> tag. Remove these props from the element.
```

Comment: Just my opinion but I've had better luck including React (or Protractor components for that matter) inside an Angular app rather than the other way around.  In then end I think mixing them has more negatives than positives especially considering Angular has directives.  I'm a big fan of React but if you need Angular IMO it's better just to use Angular for components as well.

Comment: @Ynot That was my thought too. I've seen this a couple of times and it soon gets very messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ng-app` try `data-ng-app` (and prefix `data-` to all `ng-*` directives for that matter), angular should still recognize those attributes as angular directives, and other scripts and validators should treat them as standard [HTML data-* Attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) and so ignore them and not be offended by their presense.

There is already a post about this markup:
[ng-app vs. data-ng-app, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589853/ng-app-vs-data-ng-app-what-is-the-difference)

---

**UPDATE: To fix other errors/warnings...**

**Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<body>` cannot appear as a child of `<div>`.**

Declare `data-ng-app="App"` on the body tag in your index.html file, and remove the `<body>` tag in the react component's `render` function all together.

**Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?**
In the react component's `render` function, change `class` to `className`

Comment: Updated my answer, apply those two changes and I wonder if the "Unknown props `change-background`, `colorcode` on <div> tag." warning will go away also.