# Why changeing ng-controller to data-ng-controller caused my controller to start firing

Tags: angularjs

I was having an issue where my LoginController was not firing. A console.log('test'); was not running and no breakpoints where being hit.

The only change that worked was changing ng-controller to data-ng-controller, I didn't have a reason just chancing it after trying a lot of other things. The only difference between these two that I've read is for compatibility for old IE8 but im running the latest chrome canary.

My issue is currently solved but id like to have an idea why, as I don't know why the controller wasn't working in the first place I had implemented it the same as any other in the project

Comment: which version are you using. Is it latest one.

Comment: This should not have been that way. Could you please add a minimal verifiable example of the bug you encountered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-app vs. data-ng-app, what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589853/ng-app-vs-data-ng-app-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: I cant replicate the bug, as the controller works when it is the only code being loaded. Also I agree the question is similar but I don't see where HTML validation and normalisation come in to loading this piece of code