# Angular "=" scope does not work with camelCase

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm scope property of a directive

It works fine when I use `show` as attr name.

```
<span ng-repeat="field in fields">
  <field-pill field="field" show="true"></field-pill>
</span>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app',[]);

angular.module('app')
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.fields = [1,2,3,4];
    });

angular.module('app')
  .directive('fieldPill', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="pill">{{field}}:{{show}}--<span ng-show="show">x</span></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{
        field: "=",
        "show": "="
      }
    };
  });
```

(See this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/AcqmxeCerCOtGaw9dq9t?p=preview)

But the directive doesn't load the boolean data at all when I use `x-show` as the attribute name.

```
<span ng-repeat="field in fields">
  <field-pill field="field" x-show="true"></field-pill>    
</span>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app',[]);

angular.module('app')
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.fields = [1,2,3,4];
    });

angular.module('app')
  .directive('fieldPill', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="pill">{{field}}:{{xShow}}--<span ng-show="xShow">x</span></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{
        field: "=",
        xShow: "="
      }
    };
  });
```

Can anyone explain why?

(See this plunkr for the code with `x-show` http://plnkr.co/edit/2txoY3VaShH6WggnugcE?p=preview )

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are the attribute prefixes "x-" and "data-" used in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256396/how-are-the-attribute-prefixes-x-and-data-used-in-angularjs)

Comment: Yeah.  I didn't realize that `x-` was the root cause when I asked it.

Answer (score 14):

I think it is relating to the `x-` prefix. If you change it to anything like `mShow`, `m-show`, it will work.

From the HTML5 [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html):

> Attribute names beginning with the two characters "x-" are reserved
>   for user agent use and are guaranteed to never be formally added to
>   the HTML language. For flexibility, attributes names containing
>   underscores (the U+005F LOW LINE character) are also reserved for
>   experimental purposes and are guaranteed to never be formally added to
>   the HTML language.

So avoid using `x-` for normal attribute name. :)