# TwoWay data binding in AngularJS custom directive not working in ng-show

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

My problem is that $scope.isValid is not binded to ng-show="{{isValid}}" and I don't know why.

My goal is when isValid is true this span should be visible and it is valid when there is a value in input field.

```
<span class="warning" ng-show="{{isValid}}" style="color: red;">
    Please answer the question to continue.
</span>
```

Here is plunker link to my scenario.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qZ47TFg2G741PxdARiYR?p=preview

Comment: Remove the curly braces

Comment: it is not working... if it does it shoud be like this https://infinit.io/_/gsvMZcG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I have several problems. One is related to scope binding camelcase name. Also what you said about curly brackets. and missing binding data attribute isvalid="isvalid"in directive main tag.

Similar to this problem.
[Angular "=" scope does not work with camelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18348692/angular-scope-does-not-work-with-camelcase)

Here is my working scenario in Plunker

1. it should be isvalid: '=', insted of isValid: '=',
2. I was missing isvalid="isvalid" in directive tag :

   and no curly brackets here ng-hide="isvalid"

   ```
   Working solution:
   ```

   http://plnkr.co/edit/puOeoJ37LZXZ7ZRXVTKt?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this :

```js
'use strict';

var codeArtApp = angular.module("codeArtApp", ['ui.router']);

codeArtApp.directive('submitquestion', function($http) {
 return {
  scope: { 
   questId: '@',
   answerId: '@',
   isValid: '=ngShow',
  },
  link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
   $(el).find('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    
    scope.sendQuesiton();

   })
  },
  controller: function($scope) {
   $scope.isValid = false;

   $scope.sendQuesiton = function () {
    $scope.validateQuestion();
       
       if ($scope.isValid) {
    alert('is Valid')
       } else {
         alert('Not Valid');
       }
   }

   $scope.validateQuestion = function() {
    if ($scope.answerId.length) {
      console.log($scope.answerId);
     $scope.isValid = true;
    }
   }
  }
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="codeArtApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.8" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" ng-model="edit">
    <div data-submitquestion="" data-questId="862"  data-answer_id="{{edit}}">
      <button class="btn btn__next">Следващ въпрос</button>
      <span class="warning ng-hide" ng-show="isValid == true" style="color: red;">
      Please answer the question to continue.
    </span>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can just use truthy instead of `isValid == true`

Comment: it is not working... if it does it shoud be like this infinit.io/_/gsvMZcG

Answer (score 0):

Please do `ng-show="isValid"`
You don't need the curly braces  because `ng-show` is a directive it will invoke $parse for you.

Comment: what do you mean by it invoke `$compile`?

Comment: I am sorry. Should be $parse not $compile.

Comment: it is not working... if it does it shoud be like this [link](http://infinit.io/_/gsvMZcG)