# dynamic form use angular append ng-repeat html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Excuse me, I want to use angular create dynamic form,

Then this dynamic form button click is append ng-repeat html

Button click have action , but i can't append to ng-repeat data,

I want to append multiple ng-repeat html

How can I do, please help me , thanks~!

angular

```
$scope.add_list = function()
  {
     var data = angular.element(document.getElementById("list_wrap"));
     data.append('<div class="col s6"> <label>product</label> <select class="select-with-search" name="commodity[]">  <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in commodity" value="{{value.id}}">{{value.commodity}}</option> </select> </div>');
  }
```

html

```
<div class="row">
<div id="list_wrap" class="col s12">
  <!-- append insert wrapper -->
</div>

<div  class="col s12">
  <div id="list_" class="col s12">
    <div class="col s6">
      <label>product</label>
      <select class="select-with-search" name="commodity[]">
        <option value="" selected></option>
        <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in commodity" value="{{value.id}}">{{value.commodity}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s1">
       <!-- add button -->
      <span class="cursor_pointer" ng-click="add_list()">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">playlist_add</i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not use `ng-if`and a variable?

Comment: sorry!  my english is not good.  i want click add_list function is add multiple html select.

Comment: It's not the angular way to manipulate dom in such a way. Below answer is the perfect angular way to do

Comment: @shaunak1111 thanks ! Below answer  is work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of appending slect box to dom each time use ng-repeat using an array with one element and on click insert a new element to that array.so each time new select box will be creted in the dom using ng repeat

```js
angular.module('test',[]).controller('TestController',function($scope){

$scope.selectArray = [{
  item:null
}];
$scope.commodity = [{
  id : 1,
  commodity : "First"
},{
   id :2,
  commodity : "Two"
},{
  id :3,
  commodity : "Three"
},{
  id :4,
  commodity : "Four"
}]
$scope.remove = function(index){
 $scope.selectArray.splice(index,1)
}
$scope.add_list = function()
  {
  var newItem = {
    item:null
   }
  $scope.selectArray.push(newItem);
 
    /* var data = angular.element(document.getElementById("list_wrap"));
     data.append('<div class="col s6"> <label>product</label> <select class="select-with-search" name="commodity[]">  <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in commodity" value="{{value.id}}">{{value.commodity}}</option> </select> </div>');*/
  }
  
  $scope.getSelectValue = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.selectArray,function(val,key){
       console.log(key+":"+val.item); 
    }) 
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" data-ng-app="test" data-ng-controller="TestController">
<div id="list_wrap" class="col s12">
  <!-- append insert wrapper -->
</div>

<div  class="col s12">
  <div id="list_" class="col s12">
    <div class="col s6" data-ng-repeat="select in selectArray track by $index">
      <label>product </label>
      <select class="select-with-search" data-ng-model="select.item" name="commodity[]" > 
        <option data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in commodity" value="{{value.id}}">{{value.commodity}}</option>
      </select>
      
      <button data-ng-if="!$first" data-ng-click="remove($index)">Close</button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s1">
       <!-- add button -->
      <button class="cursor_pointer" data-ng-click="add_list()">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">playlist_add</i>
      </button>
       <button class="cursor_pointer" data-ng-click="getSelectValue()">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">SUBMIT</i>
      </button>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ! this is work!  excuse me, I have a question you would like to ask, if i want to push html is Different, ex. push this html have close button, sorry maybe my english is Hard to understand....

Comment: @Bruce An easy soln: check the index if index is not first show close button

Comment: Add data-ng-click to make it HTML5 compliant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256396/how-are-the-attribute-prefixes-x-and-data-used-in-angularjs

Comment: @shaunak1111 Updated.Thanks

Comment: @XYZ very thanks!  is to solve problems ! very thanks:)

Comment: @XYZ how do you get the data from these selects?