# nested ng-repeat on table data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, xhtml

I have a scenario where I need to display a set of data in table using nested ng-repeat. Below is the data set :

```
var siteRegion = {'Site':[],'Region':[]};
```

so for each siteRegion I have multiple Site and multiple Regions, that means I have to use three ng-repeats.

I tried using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end but since I am using `xhtml` `'ng-repeat-end'` is expecting `'='` character after it.

Table Code :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Region</th>
         <th>Site</th>
       </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody ng-repeat="siteRegionInfo in siteRegion">
      <tr ng-repeat="siteList in siteRegionInfo.Site">
        <td ng-repeat-start="regionList in siteRegionInfo.Region">{{regionList.LABEL}}</td><td ng-repeat-end ></td>
        <td>{{siteList.LABEL}}</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
```

---

```
<table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Region</th>
                                    <th>Site</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead> 
                            <tbody> 
                            <tr ng-repeat-start="sitePFInfo in supplierList.SupplierInfo.SiteDependentPF" ng-init="sitePFIndex = $index">
                                <td class="col-md-2">{{sitePFInfo.Region.LABEL}}</td>
                                <td class="col-md-2">{{sitePFInfo.Site.LABEL}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-end="ng-repeat-end"></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Pushing the data via:

```
for(var j=0; j<selectedSite.length; j++){                       sitePF.Site.push({'VALUE':selectedSite[j],'LABEL':$scope.sites[findInJson($scope.sites, "VALUE",selectedSite[j])].LABEL});
                        }
for(var i=0; i<response.data.results.length; i++){
sitePF.Region.push({'VALUE':response.data.results[i].VALUE,'LABEL':response.data.results[i].LABEL});
                        }
```

Comment: Please share code for the ng-repeat loop.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: try to add x- prefix to angular specific attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256396/how-are-the-attribute-prefixes-x-and-data-used-in-angularjs

Comment: why don't you use 2 ng-repeats? 1 for region and 1 for site.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected results as per [mcve]

Comment: siteRegion is a list for which I have already used ng-repeat, inside it I have two lists one for site and another for region. I used another ng-repeat over site but then how can i use another ng-repeat for Region ?  The sample data looks like this - 
SiteRegion = {'Site1', 'Region1'
            'Site2','Region2'
     'Site3','Region3'
     'Site4','Region4'}

Comment: Where's the expected results? I don't see why you need third repeat

Comment: @charlietfl as I read it, he is just asking how to use ng-repeat-end inside valid XHTML since XHTML does not allow no-value attributes like standard HTML does.

Answer (score 1):

As the following example proves, if you are just worried that XHTML does not allow no value attributes like `ng-repeat-end` you can fix that setting the no value attribute to its own name.

In this case `ng-repeat-end="ng-repeat-end"`

(Notice: the sample below is not written to be a full XHTML compliant sample, it just serves to prove that Angularjs will just ignore the `ng-repeat-end` attribute value)

```js
angular.module("exampleApp", []).controller("exampleController", function($scope){
  $scope.exampleList = [
    {colA: "value 1.1", colB: "value 1.2", colC: "value 1.3" },
    {colA: "value 2.1", colB: "value 2.2", colC: "value 2.3" },
    {colA: "value 3.1", colB: "value 3.2", colC: "value 3.3" }
  ];
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<table ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="exampleController">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="item in exampleList">
    <td>{{item.colA}}</td>
    <td>{{item.colB}}</td>
    <td>{{item.colC}}</td>
  </tr >
  <tr ng-repeat-end="ng-repeat-end"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick response, this indeed solve the error that I was getting but now I am getting the blank table with no data.

Comment: @user7414076 that is probably worth creating another question so that we keep the two problem separate.